# Mapbox: Update custom layer paint property

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Working on a mapbox project. I have created a custom layer, and am looking to update a paint property of that layer. Methods I've tried don't work. Here are the details:

The layer I create:

```
map.addLayer({
        id: 'points-circle',
        source: 'points',
        type: 'circle',
        paint: {
          'circle-radius': pointSize*.6,
          'circle-color': {type: 'identity', property: 'color'},
        }
      })
```

Later, I try to update the `circle-radius` property, like so:

```
map.setPaintProperty('points-circle','circle-radius', pointSize*.6)
```

This fails with the error: `Error: The layer 'points-circle' does not exist in the map's style and cannot be styled.` How do I update my circle-radius of my custom added layer?

Comment: Are map and this._map the same?

Comment: @AndrewHarvey i updated the question to remove this confusion.

Comment: @astrojams1 Show us a minimal example. As an option - on jsfiddle.

Comment: If you're getting the message  `Error: The layer 'points-circle' does not exist in the map's style and cannot be styled.` then something has failed in the `addLayer` step. You need to fix that first.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to wait for the map `idle` event to fire to know that the layer is ready to be styled. See https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/#map.event:idle.

Would be nice if `map.addLayer` returned a promise that resolved when the layer was able to be styled...